# How to make a POST on OAuth 5 laravel?

Tags: laravel, post, oauth

I'm trying to use https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel
and I can authenticate and get data fine when only a GET is needed. I'd like to POST to create / update some content on Google tasks.

When I try to post using the default StreamClient:

```
    $googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists', 'POST', ['title' => 'newtitle'])
```

I get a 400 with the details:

```
    TokenResponseException in StreamClient.php line 68:
    Failed to request resource. HTTP Code: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

    in StreamClient.php line 68
    at StreamClient->retrieveResponse(object(Uri), 'title=newtitle', array('Authorization' => 'Authorization: OAuth ...', 'Content-Type' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Host' => 'Host: www.googleapis.com', 'Connection' => 'Connection: close', 'Content-length' => 'Content-length: 14'), 'POST') in AbstractService.php line 183
    at AbstractService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists', 'POST', array('title' => 'newtitle'))
```

Are the funny header params (e.g. Content-Type => Content-Type: ...) breaking it? I read that if I try CurlClient that it'll provide me more details than a simple 400 and maybe fix the auto generated headers. The error with CurlClient is:

```
    {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

I read that this can be caused by expired tokens so I made sure everything started fresh but no luck. I'm really struggling using these libraries to connect with OAuth. I basically traded one set of problems for another hah.

I tried using guzzle but as I was getting the post to work I realized I'll need to completely circumvent this oauth library that seems to be easy to use for others. If there is a way to post, that would be very awesome!

Comment: Use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop to test your API in a easy way

Comment: It's not a matter of how can I POST. It's specifically, how can I post using this specific library so I don't have to redo all the OAuth work that's been done.